# How to know if there's a newer package available in deb-src repo?

Tags: debian, apt

I added a `deb-src` line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, and build some of the packages from that repo using `apt-get source -b $package_name`.

Now how can I know if there's a newer version available in the `deb-src` repo so I can upgrade the package I installed to that latest version?